# Can I invoke functions from an rpm.spec that were declared in dependent RPMs?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Let's say I have an `rpm.spec` script that builds a `MyRPM.rpm` package:

-- rpm.spec for MyRPM.rpm

```
%define logdir %{my_dir}/logs/%{name}

Summary: bla bla bla
Name: MyRPM
Version: @@@version@@@
Release: @@@revision@@@
License: bla
Group: Applications/System
Requires: That-Other-RPM

%description
This is my RPM

%prep
%build
%install

doSomething //invoking a function
```

The `Requires` parameter there should trigger the install process of `That-Other-RPM`. Assuming that the `doSomething` function was declared in `That-Other-RPM`, can I invoke it from MyRPM's `rpm.spec` since it triggers the other one?

-- rpm.spec for That-Other-RPM.rpm

```
%define logdir %{my_dir}/logs/%{name}

Summary: bla bla bla
Name: That-Other-RPM
Version: @@@version@@@
Release: @@@revision@@@
License: bla
Group: Applications/System

%description
This is that other RPM

%prep
%build
%install

function doSomething {
   //doing something here
}
```

Comment: Note that `function doSomething {` is bash syntax, while the spec file uses bourne shell syntax, so - you'd need to use `doSomething () {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't.

functions in spec files sections like that are only available in the scriptlet in which they are defined.

There is no shared shell session between your RPM and the other RPM.